# Unit testing a JAX-WS Web Service?

Tags: unit-testing, jax-ws

Is there a way to test a JAX-WS web service? Mine is in Netbeans and I'm trying to use a web service client in the test package to do it but I wonder if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use soapUI for testing the webservices, both using a GUI or command-line

http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html
&
http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html

You can also by using netbeans test the webservices using generated tests, this is accessible by right clicking the webservice and click "test webservice", that is if you've created the web service using netbeans, if you haven't you can create a webservice from the WSDL of your web service and go from there.

If you want to use the web service client from the test package that is possible,  netbeans should generate jaxb classes neccessary for testing, you would be able to drag-n-drop the methods from the client to a test class.

Comment: Testing from Netbeans is only available for Glasfish and is in a manual manner. I'll like JUnit type of testing (reports, coverage, etc)

Comment: I'll check soapUI, looks interesting.